# Python not closing the console with system exit,how to close the console after terminating p

Tags: python, python-2.7

In Multiprocessing try to close console after terminating the process. 
here is code

```
import multiprocessing
import time

# Your foo function

def foo(n):
    for i in range(10000 * n):
        print "Tick"
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="Foo", args=(10,))
    p.start()
    time.sleep(10)

    # Terminate foo
    p.terminate()

   raise SystemExit
```

Comment: afaik terminate only works on posix systems... at a guess you are running on windows

Comment: Yes i am running on windows i want to close the terminal window after terminating the process which is not happening.